# How to expose android app data to other apps?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-storage

i am using download manager to download mp3 file using below code.

```
equest.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                    | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
            .setTitle(filename)
            .setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false)
            .setNotificationVisibility(VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)
            .setDescription("Setting as ringtone")
            .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,"tone", filename+".mp3");
```

and then use below method to set that mp3 as ringtone

```
 public boolean setRingtone(Context context,Uri uriFile){
    FileUtils fileUtils=new FileUtils(context);
    try {
        File ringtoneFile = new File(fileUtils.getPath(uriFile));

        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, ringtoneFile.getName());
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, ringtoneFile.length());
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
        //  content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Madonna");
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, fileUtils.fileDuration(ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath()));
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);


        //Insert it into the database
        Log.i("TAG", "the absolute path of the file is :"+
                ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(
                ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());




        context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"",
                null);
        Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, content);
        System.out.println("uri=="+uri);
        Log.i("TAG","the ringtone uri is :"+newUri);
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                newUri);
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}
```

This work fine but when i replace `.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,"tone", filename+".mp3");`

with `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir` ringtone is not setting up. 
This line return null `Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, content);`

I assume that is because app data is not available publicly and hidden. I need to store data in app storage because i want it to get deleted on app uninstall. Any way to expose app data to other app?. I tried using content provider but have not figured out how to do that. Please help.